# Windows Thinks Internal Hard Drive Is Removable

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, drivers, ssd, sata

I have an SSD and a HDD on Windows 10 Home prebuilt desktop PC. Windows is on the Samsung SSD. My internal Toshiba HDD shows up as removable:

[image: Ejectable HDD]

I am trying to make this no longer be the case, without removing the "safely remove hardware and eject media" tray icon entirely.

I have tried many solutions on the internet and from this site, including the one where I edit the registry value `TreatAsInternalPort` under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\storahci\Parameters\Device`, giving it a multi-string value of 0 (my device is listed as being under Bus Number 0, Target Id 2, LUN 0), but that did nothing. The thing is, a lot of the solutions have their target ID as 0, but for me, it's 2, and if it's relevant, I also seem to have a DVD drive under the same bus number of 0 but as target ID 4 (it doesn't show up as ejectable).

I have also tried looking into my BIOS for HotPlug settings or similar, but did not find such a setting.

I tried updating my "Intel(R) 300 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller" driver, which it did, then restarted, but the issue persists.

My motherboard is a Lenovo 36e9. Both hard drives appear to use default Microsoft-provided drivers dated 21 Jun 2006.

Comment: I think you have hit the nail on the head, _DVD drive under the same bus number..._ I had this problem with two drives before, Windows was observing G:\USB External drive and G:\DVD.  I opened Device Manager and removed the G: DVD drive and rebooted, make sure you have no USB drives, etc., plugged in before you reboot. Worked for me. Good Luck.

Comment: Hi @vssher, the DVD drive (or maybe it's more accurate to call it a DVD reader) is also internal, built into the case. I have never tried using it before as the PC is rather new and I have not needed to use it yet. Is your solution still applicable; should I give it a try?

Comment: Yes, just make sure you reboot after removing the DVD drive from within Windows Device Manager, you might also want to go into BIOS and do a hardware check, making sure that it detects all of the drives. I would not recommend messing with the Registry, unless you are used to editing it.

Comment: Forgive me, I've never done this before, but under the "Device Manager", I don't seem to see the DVD drive itself listed (only its driver under "DVD/CD-ROM drives"?), though I do see it under "Devices and Printers" in the control panel with an admin option to "Remove Device". Is that correct?

Comment: Click on the VIEW (Alt + V) then choose Devices by Connection. You should see DVD/CD ROM drives or similiar. Find the device and right-click on it, choose, remove. Then restart your computer. ;-) You might need to Look under __PCI bus__.

Comment: When you reboot, Windows will/should detect all the hardware, drives, etc., and rewrite the information back into the database (Registry).  Please let us know if it works.

Comment: Hm, switching to that view, I no longer see the DVD drive under "DVD/CD-ROM drives", but I do see it here: https://i.postimg.cc/TPNBx7JV/Annotation-2020-06-28-101236.png. I don't seem to have the option to remove it though. The device manager is pictured in the left window in that screenshot.

Comment: Under DVD/CD-ROM drives click on the + sign and is should reveal your device(s). Choose __Uninstall Device__

Comment: Upon doing so and restarting, my HDD is still under Bus Number 0, Target Id 2, LUN 0, showing up as removable, but now my DVD drive is no longer detected in the device manager or elsewhere.

Comment: You seem to have a problem with your computer. It sounds like it is not software. Have you looked into your BIOS? Make sure BIOS detects __all__ devices.

Comment: I have just restarted again and this time my DVD drive is back and under "Bus Number 0, Target Id 4, LUN 0" (I restarted without a little thumbdrive plugged in this time). In control panel, it momentarily stated that it was setting up before that message went away. So things are back to the way they were before. I have no problem reading and writing to/from my HDD, it's just that it shows up as removable; Windows sees it as external or somesuch.

Comment: WIndows may have confused your USB __thumbdrive__ with another (D:\), this is why __you must remove all USB, etc.__, as per my first comment. You may need to remove the two drives (d:(s)) from the Device Manager. __Always Remove external drives and reboot when removing devices from the Device Manager__. You can click on the Drive(s) in Devices Manager and view Properties. Check for the drive letters. Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks, my bad forgetting the thumbdrive earlier. So I should uninstall both the HDD and the DVD drive and try restarting again, with no other drives plugged in (I'll leave my mouse, keyboard etc in)? Just wish to be absolutely sure. Btw, I took a look at my Lenovo BIOS again and it's very bare bones with no list of devices.

Comment: My thumbdrive is/was detected as F. My SSD is C and the HDD is D. I have never seen the DVD drive show up in file explorer before. Populating its details under Volume under its properties, the DVD drive does not show me a drive letter, unlike the HDD which gets D.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click your Start menu, and choose "RUN" type in **compmgmt.msc**. When Computer Management opens you see, in the left field, Storage -> Disk Management. You should see all the drives to your system in the center field. Under volume you should be able to right-click the drive (DVD) and choose from the list, Change Drive Letter and Path... You can place a drive letter on your DVD there, if it does not have one.

Do Not change the drive letter of your Windows operating system.

Comment: After uninstalling just the DVD drive again, this time without other drives plugged in, I noticed that both my HDD and the DVD drive are curiously listed under "Bus Number 0, Target Id 4, LUN 0", but both have different drive letters (D and E respectively) and appear to be working fine. Should I try uninstalling both this time? My worry is for something to go wrong and for my HDD to no longer be recognised over a comparatively minor issue.

Comment: Under the DVD drive's Properties > Volumes and running "Populate", it did and still does not have a drive letter there despite computer management listing it as E, so I suppose my checking was wrongly done earlier. That's where I was "getting" my drive letters. My HDD did show a "D" under that menu.

Comment: @Cloud have you seen this page? https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-thinks-hard-drive-removable/ There are like, 6 suggestions there which may help. I would not recommend you edit the Registry. Here is also a very good site: https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/85077-windows-10-says-internal-hard-drive-external.html

Comment: I have tried most of those listed in the sites, and have been to the first site before. Save for updating my motherboard's BIOS drivers as I read that it can be risky. Again, don't wish to brick my PC over a comparatively minor issue.

Comment: Regarding the HDD target id 4 thing, looks like that was a mistake on my part, it is still at a value of 2, same as before. I will try uninstalling both the DVD drive and the HDD in device manager, reboot, and see what happens. If the HDD still shows up as removable, I'm not sure what else to try. Edit: I have done so, same bus numbers, same target IDs, issue persists.